# How can i get the skipped scenarios count in cucumber hooks

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Is there any cucumber command to get the skipped scenarios in cucumber ruby framework. like

```
after do |scenario|
  scenario.skipped?
end
```

Comment: scenario.status may give you what you need.  I've had scenarios skip, I'm just not sure how to force one right now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is, but there is a .skipped? method for a step, but not for the scenario itself. If you add an AfterStep hook, you will be returned an array of information about the step. From there, you can collect the information that you need.

```
AfterStep do |blah|
  blah.first.skipped?
end
```